# Comparing git changes between versions with an external directory

Tags: git, git-diff

Assume I have a directory structure like this containing a `git` tree worked on by other parties, and an `svn` tree, worked on by me, and my task is to merge in `git` changes to the `svn` code.

```
/home
  +me
    +git
      +foo
        +bar
           a.cpp
           b.cpp
    +svn
      +foo
        +bar
           a.cpp
           b.cpp
```

So, after another team member updates the upstream git repository, I can do:

```
git diff remote/origin/HEAD --name-status
```

This gives a list of modified files, like:

```
M foo/bar/b.cpp
```

So with some simple parsing I can then do for each file:

```
`git config diff.tool` foo/bar/b.cpp /home/svn/foo/bar/b.cpp
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? I read about `git difftool --no-index`, but that doesn't help simplify things and I couldn't work out how to combine both `--no-index` and `remote/origin/HEAD`.